# Consistency Combo box

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have three combo boxes in my program...

look like this -->

box1

```
number
letter
```

box2

```
1 -
2 -
3 -
4 -
5 -
```

box3

```
1 -
2 -
3 -
4 -
5 -
```

How can i do it work in this solution ?

such as... in box1 i'm selected 'number' then in box2 and box3 load this same value but in box2 when i'm selected

'1' ..... and then i'm open box3 i won't see '1' was i selected on box2.

Have a solution to do it please ?

Comment: Agree with @Jirka that JS is what you're looking for.  When you get it working (at least partially), then come back and let us know what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it pretty easily with jQuery.  The following code will listen for when the user chooses an option in the "driver" `<select>` and sets the other two `<select>` to the option with the same value.

```
<select name="driver">
    <option value="opt1"></option>
    <option value="opt2"></option>
</select>

<select name="slave1">
    <option value="opt1"></option>
    <option value="opt2"></option>
    <option value="opt3"></option>
    <option value="opt4"></option>
</select>

<select name="slave2">
    <option value="opt1"></option>
    <option value="opt2"></option>
    <option value="opt3"></option>
    <option value="opt4"></option>
</select>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('select[name="driver"]').on('change', function(e) {
        var value = $(e.target).val();

        $('select[name="slave1"], select[name="slave2"]').val(value);
    });
});
</script>
```